# Scanner wifi connectivity lost after upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 12.10, canon, scanner

Like many other posters here this seems to be a bug. I too have upgraded from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04, and my Canon MP980 All-in-one Printer worked perfectly prior to the upgrade. Now I get a `no scanners detected` message when I start Simple Scan.

Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Ubuntu is outdated, you must update to Ubuntu 14.04 with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then do the following:

http://printersquestions.com/How-to-install-Canon-PIXMA-MP980-on-Ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have other internet options other than WiFi then upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 or just if you dont want to do that or have no other option than Wi-Fi then just reinstall ubuntu with 14.04 version...